# Is it advisable to use strcmp or _tcscmp for comparing strings in Unicode versions?

Tags: c, windows, unicode, unicode-string, tchar

Is it advisable to use strcmp or _tcscmp for comparing strings in Unicode versions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_tcscmp()` is a macro.  If you define `UNICODE` it will use `wcscmp()`, otherwise it will use `strcmp()`.

Note the types `TCHAR`, `PTSTR`, etc. are similar.  They will be `WCHAR` and `PWSTR` if you define `UNICODE`, and `CHAR` and `PSTR` otherwise.

Comment: That is incorrect. `UNICODE` drives the definition of wide character string in the Win32 API. i.e when you `#include <windows.h>`. `_UNICODE` drives the c-runtimes support for wide (and multi byte) characters, and has meaning when you `#include <string.h>` (or any of the other c-runtime headers). If `_UNICODE` is defined, `_tcscmp` will be `wcscmp`, else if `_MBCS` is defined, `_tcscmp` will be `_mbcscmp`, else it will be `strcmp`.

Comment: @Chris Becke Hm, I did not know that.  I usually define both (with leading underscore and without), and now it makes sense why that's necessary.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

No, you should use _`tcscmp` . That will resolve to proper function depending upon on your compiler flags.