# Using strcmp to compare argv item with string literal isn't working as I was expecting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, argv, strcmp

I'm quite new to Visual C++ so this might be a 'schoolboy' error, but the following code is not executing as I'd expected:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (strcmp((char*)argv[1], "--help") == 0)
    {
        printf("This is the help message."); //Won't execute
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The executable, named `Test.exe` is launched as follows

```
Test.exe --help
```

I was expecting the message `This is the help message.` but I'm not seeing it - debugging reveals that the `if` condition comes out as -1 and not 0 as I'd expect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've figured out what's going on. The `argv[]` array is declared as `TCHAR*`, which is a macro that adjust the type based on whether or not Unicode has been enabled for the project (`wchat_t` if it is or `char` if it is not). The `strcmp` function, which I was trying to use, is the non-Unicode string comparison while `wcscmp` is the Unicode equivalent. The `_tcscmp` function uses the appropriate string comparison function depending on the Unicode setting. If I replace `strcmp` with `_tcscmp`, problem solved!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (_tcscmp(argv[1], _T("--help")) == 0)
    {
        printf("This is the help message."); //Will execute :)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `_T` function converts the argument to Unicode, if Unicode is enabled.

See also: [Is it advisable to use strcmp or _tcscmp for comparing strings in Unicode versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107103/strcmp-or-tcscmp-in-unicode)